# multer/filepond upload returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multer, filepond

i am currently trying to integrate multiple filepond components/instances into my react app, where the images are uploaded on button/form submit.

I have it more or less working with the code below, but i'm getting an undefined result when logging out the results in routes.js file, even though when I log out the state on submit in upload.js, i do get results.

I've tried logging out just req.files, it returns undefined, the method i've used below comes directly from multers documentation and this logs out - **TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Thanks

**upload.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from "react-filepond";
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
// import FilePondPluginFileEncode from 'filepond-plugin-file-encode';
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css";

// Register the plugins
registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, FilePondPluginImagePreview);

const API_BASE = "http://localhost:5000";

function submitForm(contentType, data, setResponse) {
  axios({
    url: `${API_BASE}/upload`,
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": contentType
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      setResponse(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      setResponse("error");
    });
}

function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [file3, setFile3] = useState("");
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");

  function uploadWithFormData() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", title);

    formData.append("file", file);

    formData.append("file3", file3);

    formData.append("desc", desc);

    submitForm("multipart/form-data", formData, msg => console.log(msg));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Upload Form</h2>
      <form>
        <label>
          File Title
          <input
            type="text"
            vaue={title}
            onChange={e => {
              setTitle(e.target.value);
            }}
            placeholder="Give a title to your upload"
          />
        </label>

        <FilePond
          name={file}
          files={file}
          allowMultiple={false}
          server={null}
          instantUpload={false}
          onupdatefiles={setFile}
        />

        <FilePond
          name={file3}
          files={file3}
          allowMultiple={false}
          server={null}
          instantUpload={false}
          onupdatefiles={setFile3}
        />

        <label>
          Description
          <textarea value={desc} onChange={e => setDesc(e.target.value)} />
        </label>

        <input
          type="button"
          value="Upload as Form"
          onClick={uploadWithFormData}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**routes.js**

```
router.post('/', upload.fields([{ name: 'file'}, { name: 'file3' }]), (req, res) => {

 console.log(req.files['file'][0]);
 console.log(req.files['file3'][0]);

  var movieData = {
    desc: req.body.desc,
    title: req.body.title,
    imgCollection:  req.files['file'],
    poster: req.files['file3']
  };

  Movie.create(movieData)
    .then(movie => res.json({ msg: 'Movie added successfully' }))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unable to add this movie' }));
});
```

image of console log

[console log upload.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjNHW.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you're loggin is the FilePond file item, it's not a File object. The file item has a `file` property that contains the actual file object, if the array you logged is what you're posting to the server you need to map it so it contains file objects instead of FilePond file items.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass any `Content-type` in headers.

Get file property from the files while appending like below,

```
formData.append("file", files.file);
```